# TFS 2015 build issue - Value cannot be null

Tags: git, tfs

Recently, when I'm trying to build a project on `TFS 2015` using `GIT`, I have encountered the following error:

```
Value cannot be null. 
Parameter name: sha1IdString
```

I can't seem to find this `Parameter` name (`sha1IdString` ) anywhere in my source code as well. Any idea what could be the cause for this?

Comment: @Could you please share the detail build logs here for troubleshooting?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT Apparently, there is no build log available as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is involved in get sources process.

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Check the build definition, make sure you have set the Git repository
  correctly and the repository that you were trying to build is not
  empty.
- Try to create a branch, then change the branch in Repository
  settings.
- Create a new build definition with the Git repository, then try it
  again.
- Create a new team project with Git , new solution, then build, to
  check if that works.

Please share your log if the problem still exist.

Similar thread for your reference: [Error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: sha1IdString](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbb43ce0-c01b-4c4f-ad7c-63c13de6cf51/error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-sha1idstring?forum=tfsbuild)

---

**UPDATE:**

According to the comment below, the solution is creating another branch under project and use the same build definition to queue build, the new branch which is working fine.

All right, Obviously, there is something wrong with the original branch. You can try below ways to narrow down the issue:

- Backup the "`.gitattributes`" first (and "`.gitignore`" file if exists), 
  then delete the files from the remote Git branch. Then copy the files
  back from normal branch to the original branch, then try it again.
- If that not work, also try to rename the original branch. then try it
  again.
- If that still not work and you still want to keep the original
  branch, just try to empty the branch, then commit and push the sources again
  to the branch.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy-MSFT for the thread. However, mine is not due to the empty repository.
I have tried to create another branch under my project and use the same build definition to queue build the new branch which is working fine.

Comment: It doesn't really resolve as my original branch still have the same issue. This is only a workaround to proceed with the deployment.

Comment: @j.f. All right, Obviously, there is something wrong with the original branch. You can try to backup the ".gitattributes" first( and ".gitignore" file if exists)  then delete the files from the remote Git branch. Then copy the files back from normal branch to the original branch, then try it again. If that not work, also try to rename the original branch. then try it again. If that still not work and you still want to keep the original branch, just try to empty the branch, then publish the sources again to the branch.

Comment: .@Andy-MSFT I realised the branch name was changed to lower case (Case-sensitive :( ) and therefore the build failed. The build definition is still pointing to the upper case branch. What I did was to change the branch in build definition to another branch, save, choose back the original branch and save again. It works once again. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It's a horrible error message. For me it was simply trying to use a branch that had been deleted.